# Laravel 8 database won't update using HTML form

Tags: php, html, database, laravel, laravel-8

I am currently creating an HTML form for the user to insert their information in the database table. However, even after I create the controller, models, and routes, the database won't update.

Here are my files,

Controller file, updateDatabase.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Models\Application;

class updateDatabase extends Controller
{
   public function update(Request $request)
   {
        return $request->input();
        $data= Application::find($request->id);
        $data->plateno=$request->plateno;
        $data->type=$request->type;
        $data->colour=$request->colour;
        $data->brand=$request->brand;
        $data->model=$request->model;
        $data->save();

        return redirect('application');
   }
}
```

Model file, Application.php

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Application extends Model
{
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'plateno',
        'type',
        'colour',
        'brand',
        'model',
        'id',
    ];

    public $timestamps=false;
}
```

View File, application.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/1000hz-bootstrap-validator/0.11.5/validator.min.js"></script>

    <link href="{{ asset('css/user.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img src="{{ asset('css/logo.png') }}">
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#"> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Applications</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Status</a></li> -->
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ route('userprofile') }}">Profile</a>
                    </li>
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <li>
                        <x-responsive-nav-link :href="route('logout')"  style="color:white"
                                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                this.closest('form').submit();">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out">{{ __('Logout') }}</span>  
                        </x-responsive-nav-link>
                    </li>
                    </form>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">  
        <div class="row content">
            <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
               <nav id="sidebar">
                   <ul class="list-unstyled components" >
                       <li >
                           <a href="{{ route('dashboard') }}">Home</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="active">
                            <a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">Application</a>
                       </li>
                       <li>
                           <a href="{{ route('status') }}">Status</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </nav> 
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-8 text-left">
                <h4>Particulars of Applicant</h4>
                <p>Please check your details </p>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="form-group">                       
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="name">Name:</label>
                            <div class="font-medium text-base text-gray-800">{{ Auth::user()->name }}</div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ Auth::user()->email }}</div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="typeUser">Student / Staff</label>
                            <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ Auth::user()->type }}</div>
                            <br>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label for="Phone">Phone Number:</label>
                            <div class="font-medium text-sm text-gray-500">{{ Auth::user()->phone }}</div>
                            <br>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <div class="container-left">
                <form method="POST" action="/application">
                     @csrf
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                        <h4>Particulars of Vehicle 1</h4>
                        <br>
                            <label for="plateno">Vehicle Registration Number:</label>
                            <input id="plateno" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Vehicle Registration Number" :value="old('plateno')" required autofocus>
                            <br>
                            <label for="colour">Colour(Vehicle):</label>
                            <input id="colour" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="colour" placeholder="Vehicle colour" :value="old('colour')" required autofocus>
                            <br>
                            <label for="type">Type of vehicle</label>
                            <input id="type" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="type" placeholder="Motorcycle / Car" :value="old('type')" required autofocus>
                            <br>
                            <label for="brand">Brand of vehicle</label>
                            <input id="brand" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand, Eg : Honda" :value="old('brand')" required autofocus>
                            <br>
                            <label for="model">Model of vehicle</label>
                            <input id="model" class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" name="model" placeholder="Model, Eg : EX5" :value="old('model')" required autofocus>
                        </div>

                        <p>*Please recheck your vehicle details</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="needs-validation">                   
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">
                                        Agree to terms and conditions
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        You must agree before submitting.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" style="background-color: #003D7B; color:white">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <hr>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
        <p>Copyright 2020  |  Developed By IIUMVeRS</p>
    </footer>       
</body>
</html>
```

Route File, web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\updateDatabase;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

//auth route for both 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() { 
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard');
});

// for users
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth', 'role:user']], function() { 
    Route::get('/dashboard/myprofile', 'App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@myprofile')->name('dashboard.myprofile');
});

//User's Application
Route::get('/application', function () {
    return view('application');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:user'])->name('application');

Route::post('/application', [updateDatabase::class, 'update']);




//User's Status
Route::get('/status', function () {
    return view('status');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:user'])->name('status');

//User's Profile
Route::get('/userprofile', function () {
    return view('userprofile');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:user'])->name('userprofile');

//Admin's Profile
Route::get('/adminprofile', function () {
    return view('adminprofile');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->name('adminprofile');

//Admin Application Record
Route::get('/records', function () {
    return view('records');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->name('records');

//Admin Application Approval
Route::get('/approval', function () {
    return view('approval');
})->middleware(['auth', 'role:admin'])->name('approval');


require __DIR__.'/auth.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

Right off the bat I see that your updateDatabase controller has a `return $request->input();` before you perform any attribute updates.

Answer (score 1):

why you're `return $request->input()` at first in the `update function` your code will stop and will not update anything because you're use return at first of the function so it'll just run first line I mean `return $request->input()`; line, remove it then try again